# DBSCAN python, AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, numpy, classification, k-means, dbscan

A seen below, I am trying to call out column on Daily Consumption and Month yet I have this error on iloc usage. Please help.
[image]

Comment: try this: your_data = df.to_numpy()[: , [0,5]]

Comment: It is giving me this eror: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-86d3fcae3613> in <module>()
----> 1 df = df.to_numpy()[: , [0,5]]

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: You are trying to use dataframe methods on a variable that is actually a numpy array.  Don't do that!

Comment: Is there a better way to code it ? im sorry I am new to this

Comment: What don't you understand?  Why your variable is an array, or why you can't treat an array like a dataframe?  I haven't looked at the code image.

Comment: `values` returns a numpy array.  Don't assign that to the `df` name, which you are already using for a dataframe.  Use a new name so you don't confuse yourself.

Comment: Consider [adding code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) instead of screenshots.